# Update COLUMNSTORE index in DB transaction

Tags: sql-server, columnstore

Is it possible to update a COLUMNSTORE index in a DB transaction? I would like to use the following SQL command inside transaction:

```
ALTER INDEX [IX_Name] ON [dbo].[TableName] REORGANIZE WITH (COMPRESS_ALL_ROW_GROUPS = ON)
```

The transaction can take a long time. Will other SQL clients be able to use the index during the transaction?

Comment: This is pretty simple to test in a Sandbox environment, what did you find out when you did so?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's your use case for reorging the columnstore in a transaction?

Comment: @DanGuzman the use case is defragmentation, since there are quite big changes in data in the table, portions of the table data gets deleted and then inserted again.

Comment: I get the defragmentation but I was wondering about the reason for the transaction.

Comment: @DanGuzman the reason for transaction is, there are other operations for other tables in the transaction that need to read from this first table.

Answer (score 0):

Note that everything in SQL runs in it's own implicit transaction if you don't specify one, so if you're just running `REORGANIZE` there's no difference between running it or wrapping it in a `BEGIN/COMMIT`.

`COMPRESSED` row groups are immutable, so let's use defragmentation rather than update for your scenario. In columnstore world an update translates into a delete + insert and a delete is "deferred". More specifically deletes are reflected in the deleted bitmap, which the engine joins with the data and returns the rows visible to your transaction. The per-row group state of the delete bitmap can be seen in the [`sys.dm_db_column_store_row_group_physical_stats`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-column-store-row-group-physical-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) DMV as the `deleted_rows` column. Also note that deleting or updating an `OPEN` or `CLOSED` row group happens in-place: for deletes you'll see the row count decrement (updates won't change the row count), however you will never see any `deleted_rows` in these two types of row groups.

So what does `REORGANIZE` do? It reads small and/or fragmented row groups and combines them, but not in place, rather it writes them out as new row groups and the old row group's state will change to `TOMBSTONE`. Old row groups will be around while they have active readers, while transactions started after the `REORGANIZE` will always read the data from the new row groups.